# Running ropsten testnet with docker error

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, ropsten, docker

I would like to try to run ethereum client at my server configured with docker geth image. But when I set the genesis block according to the command below I got an error about the reference for the genesis block file:

```
sudo docker run -it -v /mnt/ethereum_data/ropsten:/root/.ethereum ethereum/client-go:alpine init /mnt/ethereum_data/ropsten/metadata/testnet_genesis.json
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Fatal: failed to read genesis file: open /mnt/ethereum_data/ropsten/metadata/testnet_genesis.json: no such file or directory
```

Already checked and `testnet_genesis.json` is already in the right path. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the executable the path inside the container. i.e. `/root/.ethereum/testnet_genesis.json`